# Turning a Dict into a constraint

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a class `Cyc c r` which has functions for datas of the form `c m r`, where `m` is a phantom type. For example,

```
class Cyc c r where
  cyc :: (Foo m, Foo m') => c m r -> c m' r
```

I do have good reasons for not making `m` a class parameter. For the purposes of this example, the primary reason is that it reduces the number of constraints on functions. In my actual example, a more compelling need for this interface is that I work with changing and hidden phantom types, so this interface lets me get a `Cyc` constraint for any phantom type.

One downside to that choice is that I can't make `Num (c m r)` a superclass constraint of `Cyc`. My intention is that `c m r` should be a `Num` whenever `(Cyc c r, Foo m)`. The current solution is very annoying: I added  method to class `Cyc`

```
witNum :: (Foo m) => c m r -> Dict (Num (c m r))
```

which sort-of accomplishes the same thing. Now when I have a function that takes a generic `Cyc` and needs a `Num (c m r)` constraint, I can write:

```
foo :: (Cyc c r, Foo m) => c m r -> c m r
foo c = case witNum c of
  Dict -> c*2
```

Of courses I *could* add a `Num (c m r)` constraint to `foo`, but I'm trying to reduce the number of constraints, remember? `(Cyc c r, Foo m)` is supposed to imply a `Num (c m r)` constraint (and I need `Cyc c r` and `Foo m` for other purposes), so I don't want to have to write out the `Num` constraint also.

In the process of writing this question, I found a better(?) way to accomplish this, but it has its own drawbacks.

Module Foo:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Foo where

import Data.Constraint

class Foo m

class Cyc c r where
  cyc :: (Foo m, Foo m') => c m r -> c m' r  
  witNum :: (Foo m) => c m r -> Dict (Num (c m r))

instance (Foo m, Cyc c r) => Num (c m r) where
  a * b = case witNum a of
            Dict -> a * b
  fromInteger a = case witNum (undefined :: c m r) of
                    Dict -> fromInteger a

-- no Num constraint and no Dict, best of both worlds
foo :: (Foo m, Cyc c r) => c m r -> c m r
foo = (*2)
```

Module Bar:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, OverlappingInstances #-}
module Bar where

import Foo
import Data.Constraint

data Bar m r = Bar r deriving (Show)

instance (Num r) => Cyc Bar r where
  witNum _ = Dict

instance (Num r, Foo m) => Num (Bar m r) where
  (Bar a) * (Bar b) = Bar $ a*b
  fromInteger = Bar . fromInteger

instance Foo ()  

bar :: Bar () Int
bar = foo 3
```

While this approach gets me everything I'm looking for, it seems fragile. My main concerns are:

1. I'm wary of the generic instance head for `Num` in module `Foo`.
2. If any overlapping instances are imported into `Foo`, I suddenly need `IncoherentInstances` or the `Num` constraint on `foo` to defer instance selection to runtime.

Is there an alternative way to avoid using `Dict` in every function that needs `Num (c m r)` that avoids either of these downsides?

Comment: If you are using [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) the idiomatic way to define `witNum` would be `witNum :: Foo m :- Num (c m r)` which you deconstruct with e.g. `foo = case witNum :: Foo m :- Num (c m r) of Sub Dict -> (*2)` (which isn't any prettier).

Comment: That `Num (c m r)` instance head *should* scare you.

Comment: But what do I *do* about it? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 6 months of thought, I finally have an answer to my dangling comment above: add a `newtype` wrapper!

I split the `Cyc` class in two:

```
class Foo m

class Cyc c where
  cyc :: (Foo m, Foo m') => c m r -> c m' r

class EntailCyc c where
  entailCyc :: Tagged (c m r) ((Foo m, Num r) :- (Num (c m r)))
```

Then I define my `Cyc` instance as above:

```
data Bar m r = ...

instance Cyc Bar where ...

instance (Num r, Foo m) => Num (Bar m r) where ...

instance EntailCyc Bar where
  witNum _ = Dict
```

Then I define a newtype wrapper and give a generic `Cyc` instance for it:

```
newtype W c m r = W (c m r)

instance Cyc (W c m r) where cyc (W a) = W $ cyc a

instance (EntailCyc c, Foo m, Num r) => Num (W c m r) where
  (W a) + (W b) = a + b \\ witness entailCyc a
```

Finally, I change all functions that used a generic `c m r` type to use a `W c m r` type:

```
foo :: (Cyc c, EntailCyc c, Foo m, Num r) => W c m r -> W c m r
foo = (*2)
```

The point here is that `foo` might need *many* constraints (e.g., `Eq (W c m r)`, `Show (W c m r)`, etc) that would each individually require their own constraints. However, the generic instances for `W c m r` for `Eq`, `Show`, etc all have *exactly* the constraints `(EntailCyc c, Foo m, Eq/Show/... a)`, so the constraints on `foo` above are the *only* constraints I need to write!