# Which dictionary does GHC choose when more than one is in scope?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following example:

```
import Data.Constraint

class Bar a where
  bar :: a -> a

foo :: (Bar a) => Dict (Bar a) -> a -> a
foo Dict = bar
```

GHC has two choices for the dictionary to use when selecting a `Bar` instance in `foo`: it could use the dictionary from the `Bar a` constraint on `foo`, or it could use the runtime `Dict` to get a dictionary. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482576/turning-a-dict-into-a-constraint) for an example where the dictionaries correspond to *different* instances.

Which dictionary does GHC use, and why is it the "correct" choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC just picks one, and this is the correct choice. Any two dictionaries for the same constraint are supposed to be equal.

OverlappingInstances and IncoherentInstances are basically equivalent in destructive power; they both lose instance coherence by design (any two equal constraints in your program being satisfied by the same dictionary). OverlappingInstances gives you a little more ability to work out which instances will be used on a case-by-case basis, but this isn't that useful when you get to the point of passing around Dicts as first class values and so on. I would only consider using OverlappingInstances when I consider the overlapping instances extensionally equivalent (e.g., a more efficient but otherwise equal implementation for a specific type like Int), but even then, if I care enough about performance to write that specialized implementation, isn't it a performance bug if it doesn't get used when it could be?

In short, if you use OverlappingInstances, you give up the right to ask the question of which dictionary will be selected here.

Now it's true that you can break instance coherence without OverlappingInstances. In fact you can do it without orphans and without any extensions other than FlexibleInstances (arguably the problem is that the definition of "orphan" is wrong when FlexibleInstances is enabled). This is a very long-standing GHC bug, which hasn't been fixed in part because (a) it actually can't cause crashes directly as far as anybody seems to know, and (b) there might be a lot of programs that actually rely on having multiple instances for the same constraint in separate parts of the program, and that might be hard to avoid.

Getting back to the main topic, in principle it's important that GHC can select any dictionary that it has available to satisfy a constraint, because even though they are supposed to be equal, GHC might have more static information about some of them than others. Your example is a little bit too simple to be illustrative but imagine that you passed an argument to `bar`; in general GHC doesn't know anything about the dictionary passed in via `Dict` so it has to treat this as a call to an unknown function, but you called `foo` at a specific type `T` for which there was a `Bar T` instance in scope, then GHC would know that the `bar` from the `Bar a` constraint dictionary was `T`'s `bar` and could generate a call to a known function, and potentially inline `T`'s `bar` and do more optimizations as a result.

In practice, GHC is currently not this smart and it just uses the innermost dictionary available. It would probably be already better to always use the outermost dictionary. But cases like this where there are multiple dictionaries available are not very common, so we don't have good benchmarks to test on.

Comment: One might then ask why we have two extensions (incoherent/overlapping) instead of just one. One might get the impression that overlapping alone is still "safe", and only with incoherent the real trouble begins.

Comment: "Any two dictionaries for the same constraint are supposed to be equal." -- Supposed to be, but aren't. See my answer for an example of violating this claim without using either of incoherent or overlapping instances.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by the loss of instance coherence.

Answer (score 6):

It just picks one. This isn't the correct choice; it's a pretty well-known wart. You can cause crashes this way, so it's a pretty bad state of affairs. Here is a short example using nothing but `GADTs` that demonstrates that it is possible to have two *different* instances in scope at once:

```
-- file Class.hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Class where

data Dict a where
  Dict :: C a => Dict a

class C a where
  test :: a -> Bool

-- file A.hs
module A where

import Class

instance C Int where
  test _ = True

v :: Dict Int
v = Dict

-- file B.hs
module B where

import Class

instance C Int where
  test _ = False

f :: Dict Int -> Bool
f Dict = test (0 :: Int)

-- file Main.hs
import TestA
import TestB

main = print (f v)
```

You will find that `Main.hs` compiles just fine, and even runs. It prints `True` on my machine with GHC 7.10.1, but that's not a stable outcome. Turning this into a crash is left to the reader.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to cause crashes with this?

Comment: @chi I've given a snippet that shows how to get two different instances in scope. From there it's not hard -- just make some assumptions in your code about all instances being equal and you've got yourself a problem.

Comment: I don't think you can cause crashes with this, unless you count a crash caused by breaking an invariant in a module that assumes that instances are coherent, and uses this assumption to justify `unsafeCoerce` or the like. (But then I would say the crash is caused by `unsafeCoerce`.)

Comment: Specifically one might think that, while confusing `True` and `False` is harmless to an otherwise valid Haskell program, one could use associated types to get a less harmless confusion between `Int` and `Maybe Int`. But in fact GHC seems to always check type family instances for overlap.

Comment: @DanielWagner Interesting. I thought that it was forbidden to import two modules defining two instances for the same type. Probably the check is deferred on use, which would be ok if it weren't for the GADT...

Comment: @ReidBarton, I believe you are wrong. `unsafeCoerce` is much better behaved than `IncoherentInstances`. In particular, I believe GHC assumes coherence in its optimizations. I'm pretty sure you could convince GHC that a particular `case` branch is dead, then hand it an incoherent instance dictionary in a GADT blowing everything up.

Comment: @dfeuer, if you can do that, please file a bug report. It would be a previously unknown and significant bug.

Comment: @ReidBarton, maybe I'm wrong then. But the sorts of problems `IncoherentInstances` is *known* to cause are at least as bad as hard crashes anyway. I will see if I can make a hard crash of it....

Answer (score 5):

Here's a test:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances, IncoherentInstances #-}
import Data.Constraint

class    C a    where foo :: a -> String
instance C [a]  where foo _ = "[a]"
instance C [()] where foo _ = "[()]"

aDict :: Dict (C [a])
aDict = Dict

bDict :: Dict (C [()])
bDict = Dict

bar1 :: String
bar1 = case (bDict, aDict :: Dict (C [()])) of
         (Dict,Dict) -> foo [()]              -- output: "[a]"

bar2 :: String
bar2 = case (aDict :: Dict (C [()]), bDict) of
         (Dict,Dict) -> foo [()]              -- output: "[()]"
```

GHC above happens to use the "last" dictionary which was brought into scope. I wouldn't rely on this, though.

If you limit yourself to *overlapping instances*, only, then you wouldn't be able to bring in scope two different dictionaries for the same type (as far as I can see), and everything should be fine since the choice of the dictionary becomes immaterial.

However, *incoherent instances* are another beast, since they allow you to commit to a generic instance and then use it at a type which has a more specific instance. This makes it very hard to understand which instance will be used.

In short, incoherent instances are evil.

---

Update: I ran some further tests. Using only overlapping instances and an orphan instance in a separate module you can still obtain two different dictionaries for the same type. So, we need even more caveats. :-(

Comment: I'm aware that `IncoherentInstances` can lead to all sorts of nastiness, which is why my example *doesn't* use it (but it does use `OverlappingInstances and an orphan instance in another module). I didn't realize `OverlappingInstances` could also lead to undefined behavior...I thought it was "safe".

Comment: @Eric I thought so as well. Maybe it could be considered a bug but I'm not an expert on that.

Comment: @Eric For the record, using only overlapping instances I can make `Dict` to pack the "best" instance in a module: GHC commits to it even without the "incoherent" extension since there's a single best option. In another module I import that, and define an even better instance (this should be disallowed, IMHO).

Comment: Can you update your example? If you have another way in which `Overlapping` without `Incoherent` can be unsafe, I'll post a bug.

Comment: I believe it's possible to trick GHC even without `OverlappingInstances`, which is one big reason orphans are considered evil.

Comment: @Eric There's no need to post a bug: Reid Barton below states this is already known, and a long-standing one... :-/